# How to evaluate variables and encrypt data before sending in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to evaluate variables and encrypt data before sending in jmeter.
Here is my post data

```
{"client_id":"${VisitorID}","channel":"${Channel}","session":{"id":"${CurrentSessionID}","is_first_time_user":false,"page":{"name":"http://techgiant.in/application/clients.php","time_spend":12.893},"last_page":{"session_id":"${CurrentSessionID}","name":"http://techgiant.in/application/","time_spend":11.825,"last_session_id":"${CurrentSessionID}"}},"actions":{"s_id":"${CurrentSessionID}","origin":"http://techgiant.in/application/clients.php","download":{},"outbound":{},"views":{"/application/clients.php":1}},"last_session_id":"${LastSessionID}"}
```

Actually there is a cron on server, which does data processing. So i'm generating real time traffic data through thousands or users, user info is in csv sheet. I want to fetch data from sheet and want to add variables from sheet then encrypt and send.
The issue i'm facing is data is being posted as it is..variables are not being evaluated first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSR223 Test element (like a [JSR223 preprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)) to run any code you want, incl. classes from your own JARs, provided you put them into $JMETER_HOME/lib

Answer (score 0):

If your data lives in a file you can use combination of [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) and [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) JMeter Functions like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.json,,)})}
```

[image: JMeter Combine Multiple Variables]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

---

With regards to "encrypt" - there are too many possible options, you need to come up with exact requirements as the instructions will be different for each use case.